# Creating an arm64 slice for open source libraries on IOS

Tags: ios, gdal, arm64

I have successfully built armv7, armv7s and i386 slices for several open source libraries (eg. expat, freetype, libkml, jasper etc. required by gal) using a variation (depending on the library) on the script from pseudogreen (which can be found here:
http://pseudogreen.org/bzr/sandbox/iphone/build_for_iphoneos.)

Now that Apple is insisting that all apps be compiled with arm64 before Feb 1st submissions I need to create arm64 slices for all the source libraries I compile.  The above script fails when simply trying to invoke it using arm64 as a parameter vs armv7s.

Does anyone know of the necessary modifications required to the above script to get arm64 to work.  I'm assuming there may be modifications necessary to the libraries 'configure' file as well but I don't fully understand all the interconnections.

When simply invoking the script with arm64 instead of armv7s the error I get is 
"checking host system type... Invalid configuration `arm64-apple-darwin': machine`arm64-apple' not recognized"

Alternatively is there a way to include these libraries having the linker ignore the fact there are no arm64 slices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I managed to get past the above error of 'Invalid configuration' by updating the config.sub file to a newer version which includes aarch64 (aka arm64).  I've also updated to try and use Clang with the current Xcode instead of Xcode 4 and the gcc compiler as it's no longer supported.  I had been keeping a version of Xcode 4 around just for this purpose.  It now starts to process but fails with "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" fails sanity check which from what I've read means it can't find it.  I have no idea why ...